Why do we use the Jacobian determinant to change the variables of a double integral?
I've been trying to learn (the basics of) Multivariable Calculus on Khan Academy, but I've begun facing difficulties with changing the variables of a double (& triple) integral.
The problem is the following:

Suppose we wanted to evaluate the double integral
$$S=\iint_{D}(24x^2+12y^2)\ dx\ dy$$
by first applying a change of variables from $D$ to $R$:
$$x = X_{1}(u,v)=\frac{u}{4}$$
$$y = X_{2}(u,v)=\frac{v}{3}$$
What is $S$ under the change of variables?

Previously, when dealing with questions of the change of variables in functions, I was taught to just substitute $X_{1}(u,v)$ and $X_{2}(u,v)$ into the original function $f(x,y)$, and get my answer. (If I've done a bad job explaining this please tell me so that I can clarify with an example). However, I had never done a problem like this and I was stumped, so I looked at the solution, which was the following:

For a transformation $\mathbf{X}:R\rightarrow D$, the integral can be rewritten as
$$\iint_{D}f(x,y)dA = \iint_{R}f(\mathbf{X}(u,v))|J(\mathbf{X})|\ du\ dv$$
It then goes on to calculate the determinant of the Jacobian, and solves the problem.

Although I can understand how they got to the solution, I cannot comprehend the why.
So far I have only seen the Jacobian as a means of describing a local linearization, and I've been told that its determinant represents the scale factor that some arbitrary area is multiplied by as it undergoes the transformation. (Again, please tell me if I've explained this badly.)
Whilst typically with each question there are also videos/articles to go along with it, this question has provided me with no extra material and I haven't been able to understand why the Jacobian comes into play here.
Could someone please explain to me why we use the Jacobian here, and point me to any extra material which could help me understand this problem better?
Additionally, could someone explain to me the purpose of changing the variables?
(P.S., Unless I am mistaken, the author has made a mistake when they say $\mathbf{X}:R\rightarrow D$, and should it be $\mathbf{X}:D\rightarrow R$)
(Link to the quiz: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/integrating-multivariable-functions/x786f2022:change-variables/e/change-of-variables--bound)
Thank you!

Look at a proof of this theorem.

Which theorem are you referring to?

The one you wrote and asked "why" it holds: $\iint_{D}f(x,y)dxdy = \iint_{X^{-1}(D)}f(X(u,v))|J(X)|\ du\ dv$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables

"I've been told that its determinant represents the scale factor that some arbitrary area is multiplied by as it undergoes the transformation."
This is the key idea here. Think of $dydy$ as the area of a small rectangle with sides $dx$ and $dy$. Under the transformation/change of coordinates, the small rectangle is turned into a small parallelogram with area $\det(J)dudv$ where $u,v$ are the new coordinates. So, we substitute the new variables $x=x(u,v)$ and $y=y(u,v)$ into the integrand $f(x,y)$ and replace the small area $dxdy$ with $\det(J)dudv$.

Would this just work for linear transformations or would it work for any change of variables? (also thanks!)

It works for any continuously differentiable change of coordinates. The reason is that on a small enough scale, a continuously differentiable function is very nearly linear, and the integral involves the limit as the size of the small rectangles tend to zero.
